# Write to specific objects in json. Python

Tags: python, json, database

I want to create a program that loads a json file, reads it and then adds a 
object to a list.

```
import json

newo = {
    "balance": "1234",
    "time": "forever"
}

with open("json.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

with open("json.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(newo, f)
```

This is the python file I have been using.

```
{ 
    "cointiply": [
        {
            "balance" : "242537",
            "time": "28.05.2019"
        },
        {
            "balance": "246362",
            "time": "29.05.2019"
        }
    ]
}
```

And that's the json file.

I now want the newo list to be inserted into the json list "cointiply".

Any idea how that could be done?
Because right now the "newo" list is deleting every think in the json file and then just inserted like the file would have been empty.

Comment: you read the existing values into `data` but never use them. merge the two dictionaries `data` and `newo` and write back the combined dictionary back into the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `list.append`

**Ex:**

```
import json

newo = {
    "balance": "1234",
    "time": "forever"
}

with open("json.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

data["cointiply"].append(newo)  #Append newo

with open("json.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
>>> demo = {
...     "cointiply": [
...         {
...             "balance" : "242537",
...             "time": "28.05.2019"
...         },
...         {
...             "balance": "246362",
...             "time": "29.05.2019"
...         }
...     ]
... }
>>> newo = {
...     "balance": "1234",
...     "time": "forever"
... }
>>> demo["cointiply"].append(newo)
>>> demo
{'cointiply': [{'balance': '242537', 'time': '28.05.2019'}, {'balance': '246362', 'time': '29.05.2019'}, {'balance': '1234', 'time': 'forever'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temporary file, write your new data to it and then replace the two files, instead of opening the same file twice. Regarding the list - you need to use `append` in order to add your new data to the `cointiply` element:

```py
from os import remove
from shutil import move
from tempfile import mkstemp

newo = {
    "balance": "1234",
    "time": "forever"
}


fh, abs_path = mkstemp()
file_path = "json.json"
with open(fh, "w") as newf, open(file_path, "r") as oldf:
    data = json.load(oldf)
    data["cointiply"].append(newo)
    json.dump(data, newf)
    # Remove original file
    remove(file_path)
    # Move new file
    move(abs_path, file_path)
```